# Polymorphic data structures in C

Tags: c, oop, data-structures, polymorphism

I am a C beginner with quite a lot of OOP experience (C#) and I am having trouble understanding how some notion of "polymorphism" can be achieved in C.

Right now, I am thinking how to capture the logical structure of a file system using structs. I have a folder that contains both folders and files. Folders in this folder can contain another files and folders, etc.

My approach:

```
typedef enum { file, folder } node_type;

struct node;
typedef struct {
    node_type type;
    char *name;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *children;
} node;
```

Is this the best I can do? I have found a lot of posts on "polymorphism in C", but I would like to see how a polymorphic data structure like this can be built cleanly and efficiently (in terms of memory wasted on unused members of those structures).

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't shown what you're trying to achieve. Are you supposed to have two subclasses of a single base class? Do you need virtual method dispatch? How do you want to use them?

Comment: @Useless I would like to have in-memory representation of the file system hierarchy that can easily be traversed. If I did this in C, I would probably create a Node abstract class that would hold the name and two descendant classes File and Folder. Folder would add a `List<Node> children`.

Comment: Look at the Union statement/construct in C.

Comment: So after all that the fundamental problem is you want both folders and files represented by the same node layout, where folders need a child (subfolders and contained files) and a sibling pointer list, while files just need the sibling list. Does that about sum it up?

Comment: @WhozCraig Not necessarily. The idea to define "one struct to hold it all" is the only one that came to my mind. My question is, is there a better way?

Comment: In Unix there is a standard representation for directory entries called "dirent". It looks much as above, with a discriminator field to indicate what type of file is being referenced: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/dirent.5.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12974623/1673391

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand what you want - I'm unsure but I guess you want to do something like that:

```
typedef struct
{
   int type; // file or folder?
} Item;

typedef struct
{
   struct A;
   // data related to a file
} File;

typedef struct
{
   struct A;
   // data related to a folder - like pointer to list of Item
} Folder;
```

As long as both structure follow the same memory mapping (same variables) and adds to it as a child, you'll be able to use the pointer properly in both structs.

Check this one out as well: [How can I simulate OO-style polymorphism in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524033/how-can-i-simulate-oo-style-polymorphism-in-c)

Edit: I'm not sure about the syntax above (took it from the link above). I'm used to writing it this way instead:

```
typedef struct
{
  int type;
  // data for file
} File;

typedef struct
{
  int type;
  // data for folder - list, etc
} Folder;
```

Comment: do you mean `Item A` instead of `struct A`?

Comment: Thanks for interesting reading. Is this common to C programs?

Comment: @David "is it common?" it is used, but more common is "Abstract Data Type" programming where you use a struct to define a single (non-polymorphic) data type and code a bunch of methods against it. One example of this kind of "struct embedding inheritance" is the BSD sockets type sockaddr. This is like the base type, then sockaddr_in provides fields for representing internet addresses. Most sockets functions are polymorphic in that they can deal with different types of sockaddr including sockaddr_in.

Comment: @RossBencina Is my understanding correct that pointer to a struct is actually pointer to its first member?

Comment: @David http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312555/in-c-does-a-pointer-to-a-structure-always-point-to-its-first-member

Answer (score 2):

C has no intrinsic notion of polymorphism.

You will end up implementing the mechanisms that you want from scratch. That's not a bad thing. It gives you a lot more flexibility. For example, C++ virtual methods are hard-wired per class, you can't change method pointers per-instance.

Here are a few ideas:

Your node_type field provides a way to do a runtime type query. Going further, you can pack multiple types into one struct using a discriminated (or tagged) union: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union. I'm not sure whether a variant type qualifies as OO though.

Polymorphism is usually about behavior. You could store [function pointers](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html) ("methods") in the struct, with pointers to different functions providing different behavior for different object instances. The C++ way of doing things is for each class to have a table of function pointers, then each object instance references the table for its class (incidentally the table pointers can also play the role of your node_type for RTTI). This is called a [virtual method table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

Data inheritance means that subclasses contain all of the base class' data members plus some extra stuff. In C the easiest way to do this is by embedding the base class struct at the head of the derived class struct. That way a pointer to derived is a pointer to base.

```
typedef struct BaseClass {
  int baseMember;
} BaseClass;

typedef struct DerivedClass {
  BaseClass base;
  int derivedMember;
} DerivedClass;
```

You could do worse than read "Inside the C++ Object Model" by Stanley B. Lippman. For example, this will help if you want to get an idea of how to implement multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an illustration of old-school C polymorphism, based on ancient memories of X/Motif.

If you just want a discriminated union (or even just a typed structure with a child pointer that may be null), it's probably simpler in your case.

```
enum NodeType { TFile, TFolder };
struct Node {
    enum NodeType type;
    const char *name;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct FileNode {
    struct Node base_;
};

struct FolderNode {
    struct Node base_;
    struct Node *children;
    /* assuming children are linked with their next pointers ... */
};
```

Here are the constructors - I'll leave populating the linked lists as an exercise for the reader ...

```
struct Node* create_file(const char *name) {
    struct FileNode *file = malloc(sizeof(*file));
    file->base_.type = TFile;
    file->base_.name = name; /* strdup? */
    file->base_.next = NULL;
    return &file->base_;
}

struct Node* create_folder(const char *name) {
    struct FolderNode *folder = malloc(sizeof(*folder));
    folder->base_.type = TFolder;
    folder->base_.name = name;
    folder->base_.next = NULL;
    folder->children = NULL;
    return &folder->base_;
}
```

Now we can walk a hierarchy, checking the type of each node and responding appropriately. This relies on the first member subobject having zero offset to the parent - if that doesn't hold (or you need multiple inheritance), you have to use `offsetof` to convert between base and "derived" types.

```
void walk(struct Node *root,
          void (*on_file)(struct FileNode *),
          void (*on_folder)(struct FolderNode *))
{
    struct Node *cur = root;
    struct FileNode *file;
    struct FolderNode *folder;

    for (; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next) {
        switch (cur->type) {
        case TFile:
            file = (struct FileNode *)cur;
            on_file(file);
            break;
        case TFolder:
            folder = (struct FolderNode *)cur;
            on_folder(folder);
            walk(folder->children, on_file, on_folder);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we have a sort-of-polymorphic base type, but instead of switching on the type enumeration we could have a more completely polymorphic setup with virtual functions. Just add a function pointer to `Node`, something like:

```
void (*visit)(struct Node *self,
             void (*on_file)(struct FileNode *),
             void (*on_folder)(struct FolderNode *));
```

and have `create_file` and `create_folder` set it to an appropriate function (say, `visit_file` or `visit_folder`). Then, instead of switching on the enumerated type, `walk` would just call

```
cur->visit(cur, on_file, on_folder);
```