# Defining a pointer function inside a struct

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

So I was trying to accomplish to write a struct with pointer functions in it and this is what I wrote

```
typedef struct Coordinates {
    float x; 
    float y;
} Coord;

typedef struct Parallelograms {
        Coord upperR, lowerL;
        float base;
        float (*areaFunc)(float base, Coord upperR, Coord lowerL);
        float (*perimeter)(float base, Coord upperR, Coord lowerL);
} Parallelogram;
```

This is where I define the function:

```
float area(float base, Coord upperR, Coord lowerL) {
    return (base*(upperR.y-lowerL.y));
}
```

And then in some other function I call it this way:

```
Parallelogram para;   
para.areaFunc = area;
```

The only thing is that when I try to print it

```
printf("Area = %.2f", array[i].area);
```

(with array being the array of Parallelogram type of objects)
It returns this error when compiling:

> format specifies type 'double' but the argument
>         has type 'float (*)(float, Coord, Coord)' (aka 'float (*)(float, struct
>         Coordinates, struct Coordinates)') [-Werror,-Wformat]
>     ...printf("#  Area = %.2f                  #\n", array[I].areaFunc);

I thought I got the pointer functions right, so how can I convert the pointer function to the actual value that it should return?

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mcve] that replicates the problem, and show it to us. The code you show doesn't match the error you get. And please include a *full* and *complete* copy-paste of the build output of that example. Also please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry for that... I was making one but I got the answer from Sean Bright before I could finish it. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `array` is an array of `Parallelogram`s:

```
printf("Area = %.2f", array[i].areaFunc(array[i].base, array[i].upperR, array[i].lowerL));
```

Your current code is trying to print out a function pointer as a floating point number, which is obviously wrong. You need to *call* the function that is being pointed to.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. But if it's so long, what are the advantages of using the pointer functions? Isn't it the same defining a function with the struct type param and then calling it by her self?

Comment: @L_Cleo If you're always calling the same function, yes, but function pointers allow you to call different functions based on data. One could have `area` functions for squares and circles, too, and keep the same interface.

Comment: @NeilEdelman Ok, well then I guess I would have to make a sample program that really would see those pointer functions as more convenient than the simple function definition. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971995/how-pointers-to-function-as-struct-member-useful-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351733/can-you-write-object-oriented-code-in-c and the Wikipedia article has some examples, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer.