# Execution of code on the stack

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation, stack

I am new to basics of gcc compilation. As far as I know the stack is inexecutable for security reasons. Then how can we have code on stack and execute. I observed this in case of a function returning pointer to a function. it does not return pointer to code but rather to a location on stack which has the code to be executed. How is that allowed in linux?

It is already done by gcc. I want to know how is it even possible?

Here is the c code:

```
     #include<stdio.h>

    typedef int (* funcptr) ();


funcptr f ()
{

  int g ()
  {

}
return (&g);
}


main ()
{
  funcptr fp;
  fp = f();

  fp ();

 }
```

And here is the portion of the assembly code geerating code on the stack:

```
    #Starting trampoline code. The trampoline code is a small
    #piece of code set up inside the stack!!!. This code, when
    #executed, loads ecx with the static link and calls the
    #function g
        movb    $-71, (%eax)    # This is B9, the opcode for
                                  "movl address_in_next_loc ecx"
                                  this, when executed, will
                                  load the static link in ecx

        movl    %edx, 1(%eax)   # address_in_next_loc=ebp-16
                                  the static link effectively

        movb    $-23, 5(%eax)   # This is E9. the opcode for
                                  jmp addr_nxt_ins + offset_
                                  in_nxt_loc
                                  Since the offset_in_nxt_loc 
                                  is &g - addr_nxt_ins, this
                                  results in a jump to &g

        movl    $g.1831, %ecx   # Stores &g - addr_nxt_ins
        leal    10(%eax), %edx  #
        subl    %edx, %ecx  # 
        movl    %ecx, %edx  # 
        movl    %edx, 6(%eax)   # 
    #End of trampoline code
```

Comment: What makes you say gcc does this?

Comment: Because I read the assembly created by gcc. I created the assembly and read it.

Comment: Can you show this assembly code?

Comment: That's how the *pointer to the code* gets on the stack; the *code* for that function is not.

Comment: No, I know the difference between pointer and code itself. The stack contains code itself. Maybe I made a typo. return function as an object. and you will see code on the stack(not all the function code but some code).

Comment: You would need to provide an example of that.

Comment: Functions aren't objects in C; if you have evidence to the contrary, please show it.

Comment: I can understand code being copied to a stack - the stack is writeable, so it could happen: a bug could do it, and I would expect a segfault/AV to follow on shortly.....

Comment: The entire function code is not copied. When we call a function we need to provide environment pointer along with params & return address. So what happens is it creates two intruction on stack one is to jump to the code and other is to load environment pointer. and returns a pointer to it. So when a call to returned function is made from main it actually executes the code from stack to jump to actual function code. By environment pointer I mean static link.

Comment: Sounds like a thunk.  Would like to see the _examples_ !!!

Comment: I have added an example in the question description.

Comment: Please 1) remove any unnecessary C code from your example, 2) fix the various compiler warnings (unused variables, missing return types / values), 3) add the *specific* command line you are using to compile / disassemble the code. I was not able to reproduce your results.

Comment: Removed unnecessary code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C code contains a nested function, so GCC will set the `.note.GNU-stack` section of the generated object file to `x` (indicating an executable stack is required).

When the linker is invoked, it checks all supplied object files for this section. Because one of the input files has `.note.GNU-stack` set to `x`, the linker knows the stack must be executable.

To indicate this, the ELF header `GNU_STACK` in the final executable has the flag `PF_X` added to it.

The command:

```
readelf -l a.out | grep -A1 GNU_STACK
```

Should allow you to see the `RWE` flag set instead of `RW`.

The kernel specifically looks for this header when setting up the memory map for the process.

More details in the [original patch](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2003-05/msg00741.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You would allocate memory from heap as opposed to the stack.  But that might not do the trick, either, as modern processors/OSes allow for distinguishing between memory regions containing code and those containing data (for obvious security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you assume that the stack is holding the code itself. That may not be the case. Stack is just a holder for the pointer to the code area.

You can learn more on how stack works [here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html)

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18283676/6134918) shows that the function pointer or the function itself would need the code location

Comment: The stack holds some code not the all function code but some code. for jumping and setting static link etc. but the code is there on stack.

Comment: Maybe this link will help: http://hokstad.com/how-to-implement-closures